# How to make long session time in Bitwise SSH client?

Tags: ssh, openssh

I use Bitwise SSH client to connect remote machines. When i do SSH, sometimes my terminal closes frequently..I think it is due to some session timeout(?). It is really difficult to work in a remote machine if terminal closes very frequently.

How can i make my terminal alive for long time?

Comment: This isn't a programming question at all and has nothing to do on SO; That said, session timeout is a kind of security measure and you should be very carefull touching it.

Comment: I believe there is a setting in that tool..i could not find that..